# System.out.print.ln Text doesn't seem to show after scanner active

Tags: java

System.out.print.ln Text doesn't seem to show after scanner active.
The first system.out.println doesnt show could someone please help me
I am new to java coding and need help so please dont get my account banned from asking questions

```
import java.util.*;
public class CrossStick {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    String l1 = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Fiddlesticks!"+"Give me a 5 letter word: "+ l1);
    l1 =l1.toUpperCase();
    char let1 = l1.charAt(0);
    char let2 = l1.charAt(1);
    char let3 = l1.charAt(2);
    char let4 = l1.charAt(3);
    char let5 = l1.charAt(4);
    System.out.println(let1);
    System.out.println(let2);
    System.out.println(let3);
    System.out.println(let4);
    System.out.println(let5);

        kb.close();
}
```

}

Comment: You should probably prompt for input before attempting to read a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Fiddlesticks! Give me a 5 letter word: ");
        String l1 = kb.nextLine();
        l1 =l1.toUpperCase();
        char let1 = l1.charAt(0);
        char let2 = l1.charAt(1);
        char let3 = l1.charAt(2);
        char let4 = l1.charAt(3);
        char let5 = l1.charAt(4);
        System.out.println(let1);
        System.out.println(let2);
        System.out.println(let3);
        System.out.println(let4);
        System.out.println(let5);

        kb.close();
```

Try this.

Comment: The scanner input needs to be after user prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The `String l1 = kb.nextLine();` is still searching through the input until it gets a line separator, which you have not input yet. Put this `readLine` after the prompt to get the order you are expecting.

```
System.out.println("Fiddlesticks!"+"Give me a 5 letter word: "+ l1);
String l1 = kb.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a text before you prompt the user you should first print the text and then wait for input:

```
 System.out.print("Fiddlesticks!"+"Give me a 5 letter word: ");
 String l1 = kb.nextLine();
```

Note the `System.out.print()` and not `System.out.println()`, that is because `.print()` will not add a new line after it prints the text, just to make it look better.